# Yii2 - DataTable show data based on default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, yii2

I am currently working on Datatables and i am having trouble with it.

i have this sample table

[image]

in my controller, im getting all the data currently in my db..
The thing is i want my datatable to display only based on a default value..

like example, i want to display only status = 01.

so in my first onload, only the data with status 01 is displayed.
How do i do this in datatable..

this is my `datatable.js`

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var extensions = {
        "sFilter": "inputDivFilter",
        "sFilterInput": "form-control input-sm inputFilter",
        "sLength": "selectDiv",
        "sLengthSelect": "form-control input-sm",
        "sInfo" : "selectDiv"
    };

    $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "language" : {
            "sProcessing":   "処理中...",
            "sLengthMenu":   "_MENU_ 件表示",
            "sZeroRecords":  "データはありません。",
            "sInfo":         " _TOTAL_ 件中 _START_ から _END_ まで表示",
            "sInfoEmpty":    " 0 件中 0 から 0 まで表示",
            "sInfoFiltered": "（全 _MAX_ 件より抽出）",
            "sInfoPostFix":  "",
            "sSearch":       "検索:",
            "sUrl":          "",
            "sEmptyTable":   "表示するデータはありません。",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "先頭",
                "sPrevious": "前",
                "sNext":     "次",
                "sLast":     "最終"
            }
        },
    });

    /* use for search input, select entries, info, and pagination */
    // Used when bJQueryUI is false
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, extensions);
    // Used when bJQueryUI is true
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses, extensions);

    $('#movie_table').DataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 2 ],
              "sType": "date", "aTargets": [ 0 ],
            }
        ],
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100], [50, 100]],
    });

   /* default searchbox outside of datatable*/
    var table = $('#movie_table').DataTable();

    /* searching for dropdown status search */
    $('#article_status_search').on('change', function () {
        table.columns(0).search(this.value).draw();
    });



}); //end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of DataTables, you can use the [`searchCols`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/searchCols) option to use an initial filter in DataTables 1.10:

```
"searchCols": [
    { "search": "1" },
    null,
    null
]
```

Or the [`aoSearchCols`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#aoSearchCols) option for DataTables version 1.9 and earlier:

```
"aoSearchCols": [
    { "sSearch": "1" },
    null,
    null
]
```

You should add this option to your DataTable initialization. In your case after the line `"lengthMenu": [[50, 100], [50, 100]],`.

The `searchCols` option requires an array with the same length of the columns. If you want to search the second row, you should set the first value to `null` and use the `search` option on the second index. If you have 5 columns, you should have the search, and 4 times `null`.

Comment: hi @Ivar.. uhm. actually the searching is already ok though. what im trying to say is that during the first load of my page, only the default value of status is displayed. example is status = 1. on my first load of the page, only status=1 is displayed.

Comment: @litlitDM So you want to search by default on (for example) 1? Or do you want only 1 to load, and be able to search for everything, as long as it is 1?

Comment: i can be able to search for everything. but on the first open of the page, meaning the first load of the page, only 1 can be seen. but i can still be able to search for everything.